# linking C++ and Python using Boost.Python, on Remote Hosting

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost-python, pythonanywhere

First, [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) is an amazing remote hosting site, and it would be great if it weren't just for `python`.

I've read loads of solutions, trying to get [this](https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/tree/main/01-HelloWorld) simple example to work, in an attempt to use `c++` code, using `python` code hosted in [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

c++ code

```
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

In my account in pythonanywhere I did the following:

1. Create hello.cpp file with C++ code and upload it.
2. Run the following two cmds:

`gcc -o middle -c -fPIC -I /usr/include/python3.8/ -L /usr/include/python3.8/ hello.cpp`

`gcc -o hello.so -shared middle -lboost_python -lpython3.8`

The second command terminates unexpectedly showing the error:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python`

If I run the second command without the `-lboost_python` argument, it succeeds, but when I use python an error is thrown.

```
$ python3.8
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/Ottoman/hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

I need two kinds of answers. First, what am I doing wrong and how can I solve my problem? Second, What I'm trying to do is good practice?, since my ultimate goal is to execute much more complex C++ code. If not, what alternatives do I have? Thank you!!!

Comment: So you solved your problem, which was caused by a mere typo. Close this question then. If you have a new question now, ask a new question, but don't warp the topic of this initial one. As a new user here, please also read [ask] and take the [tour]. BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=undefined+symbol%3A+_ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `-lboost_python` you should use `-lboost_python38`, since you are using python3.8.